# Using readLong() after readLine() for socket communication

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

Why does this program not work properly? Client reads SOME_MESSAGE and after that nothing happens. It seems that println method from server in some way have influence on transferring long type numbers.

SERVER

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(9999);
    while (true) {
      Socket sock = socket.accept();
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
          new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream())), true);
      DataOutputStream outByte = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
      out.println("SOME_MESSAGE");
      outByte.writeLong(948L);
    }
  }
}
```

CLIENT

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9999);
    DataInputStream inByte = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        sock.getInputStream()));

    System.out.println(in.readLine());
    long number = inByte.readLong();
    System.out.println(number);
  }
}
```

Comment: Works for me when I tested it (Java 7).

Comment: Does it work if you place the `println` and `writeLong` inside `synchronized(this) { ... }` blocks?

Comment: @martijno What would be the rationale behind that?

Comment: I was thinking part of the problem might be that you're writing data to the underlying `OutputStream` via two different wrappers (`out` and `outByte`), both of which have internal buffers. Actually, synchronization doesn't help here of course, never mind. Perhaps flushing in between the calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the `BufferedReader` is buffering bytes from the socket's input stream, so the long 948 value isn't in the `DataInputStream` because the `BufferedReader` has it read and is buffering it. In general you don't want to be using 2 different wrappers around the same underlying stream, especially if one is buffered. Same with your `Server` class, but that seems to at least be working.

Your Client needs to use only one wrapper for the socket's input stream. You should just stick with the `DataInputStream` and along with the Server code, use `DataInputStream.readUTF()` on the Client while using `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()` on the Server, getting rid of both the `BufferedReader` and the `PrintWriter`.

So on the Server:

```
while(true) {
    Socket sock = socket.accept();
    DataOutputStream outByte = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    outByte.writeUTF("SOME_MESSAGE");
    outByte.writeLong(948L);
    outByte.flush();
```

}

and on the Client:

```
public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception
{
    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1",9999);
    DataInputStream inByte = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

    System.out.println(inByte.readUTF());
    long number  = inByte.readLong();
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Comment: I agree to the solution but I am not convinced about why this is happening? `PrintWriter` if `autoflush` true will flush the data written that is why "SOME_MESSAGE" is received at the client side. Now even if both streams flushed after writing long then also `'long'` is never received at client side it is like disappeared?

Comment: Thanks for advice. I have accustomed to use PrintWriter and Scanner to communicate, but the problem was i needed to transfer file so i had to use InputStream and OutputStream beside Scanner and PrintWriter. How can i convert from UTF-8 to default character set when i read with readUTF() and for how much bytes will writeUTF() increase size of transfered characters throw network?

Comment: @AmitDeshpande The problem isn't on the Server's end and the flushing, it's the Client reading. The BufferedReader reads the Long from `sock.getInputStream()` and it's buffered, so when you call `readLong()`, the underlying `sock.getInputStream()` has nothing to be read.

Comment: @user1610362 You won't need to convert anything because you have String objects already, the encoding is purely for transferring through the DataInput/Output streams. The UTF methods use a [modified UTF-8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8), so there isn't any extra size being transferred, and in the case of actual UTF-8 data, it is **less** bytes to use read/writeUTF().

Comment: Can i buffer DataOutputStream and DataInputStream?

Comment: @user1610362 You mean like: `DataInputStream inByte = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream()));`?

Comment: How can i use ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream beside DataInputStream and DataOutputStream?

Comment: @user1610362 Yes you can buffer the `DataInputStream`, but it just makes the problem worse. Now you have *two* buffers stealing data from each other. You need to revise your application protocol so that you can use the same streams at both ends to send and receive everything. You could use object streams: note that they export all the same methods as DataInput/Output streams plus the object methods.

Comment: I just checked objecinputstream in java api and i couldn't believe that it has all the methods that i need.Thanks

Comment: I found bug which causes deadlock when i try to instantiate ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream using socket. http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4162466

Comment: @user1610362 That was submitted (and closed) back in 1998, are you using JDK 1.2?

Comment: I'm using JDK 7 but i cannot instantiate ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream one behind other.

Comment: @user1610362 yeah, you need to do it the other way around (see the **Workaround** section in that link)

Comment: @user1610362 Try again. The workaround works for everybody else. Create the ObjectOutputStream first, at both ends.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting that java does not allow to do that having said that there is always a better solution. You can use serialization to do your job.

create a interface `PayLoad` like below

```
import java.io.Serializable;


public interface PayLoad extends Serializable
{
String getMessage();
//Java does not allow to define byte array of long
int getLength();

byte[] getbytes();

}
```

Then create an Implementation class like below

```
public class FilePayLoad implements PayLoad
{

private final String message;
private final int length;
private final byte[] bytes;

public FilePayLoad(String message, int length, byte[] bytes)
{
    this.message = message;
    this.length = length;
    this.bytes = bytes;

}

@Override
public String getMessage()
{
    return this.message;
}

@Override
public int getLength()
{
    return this.length;
}

@Override
public byte[] getbytes()
{
    return this.bytes;
}

}
```

Now change your server and client like below

Server

```
public class Server
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(9999);
    while (true)
    {
        Socket sock = socket.accept();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        byte[] bytes = "SOME_MESSAGE".getBytes();
        out.writeObject(new FilePayLoad("SOME_MESSAGE", bytes.length, bytes));
        out.flush();
    }
}
}
```

Client

```
public class Client
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9999);
    ObjectInputStream inByte = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    PayLoad payLoad = (PayLoad) inByte.readObject();
    System.out.println(payLoad.getMessage());
    System.out.println(payLoad.getLength());
    System.out.println(new String(payLoad.getbytes()));
}

}
```

Comment: I know that but i needed to use DataInputStream to read bytes from stream with read(byte[],off,len) because later in code i transferred byte files so i also used that for reading that long number which in my case represent size of file.